# How do I install Azure Powershell *on* a cloud service

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have need for a cloud based intranet application to run Azure Powershell. I've done a bunch of digging and I cannot find anywhere that gives me an understanding of the process I need to follow to actually get Azure Powershell to install on my Cloud Service machine so that my app can interact with and manage my Azure environment.

If I run the application with my Azure Powershell scripts locally, everthing is fine, but I cannot for the life of me get it to function correctly on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you check here: https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-%E2%80%93-what-are-the-options/

You can see how it can be done in technique 2.

In short you have to add the installer to your solution. (Make sure it is copy-local) and then install it from a bat file for example.